# JavaScript React hiding source files in sources tab

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-chrome, ubuntu

I have recently developed a website, it's NodeJs (on Ubuntu) and running a React app. The problem is, for example, on Chrome; when you right-click on the website and check sources you can see the source codes and all the files. I want to hide all of them.

In this section, I want to hide the source codes (files) in the server.
[image]

I tried couple of solutions on the internet but none of them worked.

For example,

I've added `"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",` in `package.json` and then I did run `pm2 reload` (also yarn build etc)

I've created a file called `.env` and added this line `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` in it.

None of them has worked. My website is currently active right now and I want to hide source files, how can I hide these source files from sources tab so people can't see the source codes?

Comment: Since we don't know anything about your build process we don't know how the files are actually created and what exactly you are talking about. Yes, you can prevent the generation of source maps, which could make the source files less readable, but you cannot prevent anyone from accessing the source of the code that actual runs in the browser because obviously the code needs to be downloaded onto the user's machine to be executed. And JavaScript code is still distributed as text, not compiled binaries.

Comment: @FelixKling I just first used `create-react-app` then customized the .js files. My goal is at least making them less readable, I thought it was a simple command like adding some lines to package.json then reload the app.

Comment: The docs contains a section about production builds: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After long research, I have found the solution.**

1. Create a file called `.env` in your project. The name of the file is just `.env`.
2. In that `.env` file put this line `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` and save.
3. Then, run `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
4. This will generate a `build` folder for production. After that, depends on what you are using, run this build file for running the website. For example, I'm using `pm2` on my Ubuntu server, so I've used `pm2 serve build 3000 --spa` (my website is running on port 3000) Also be careful you are in the same path with the `build` folder.

**That's it**. Now all the source code files are gone and website works like a charm.